# Почение Map<String, Long> из Set<String>

Tags: java

Доброй ночи, всем. Вроде простая задача. Есть список строк. Из него нужно получить `Map`, где ключ - уникальные значения из списка, значение - количество повторений в списке. Необходимо использовать `Stream API`. На самом деле там даже чуть сложнее. Я написал первый шаг, но и он у меня не получается.

Доделал до такого

```
List<String> strings =
        List.of("Java", "JaVA", "PHP", "JS", "java", "jS", "Python", "java");
Map<String, Long> result =
        strings.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Function.identity(),
                        s -> Collections.frequency(strings, s)));
```

Comment: `Map<String, Long> frequencyMap =  strings.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));`  [тыц](https://www.techiedelight.com/count-frequency-elements-list-java/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Исходный код можно немного доработать

1. на выходе ожидается Map<String, Long>, а Collections.frequency(strings, s) возвращает int, поэтому надо бы преобразовать в Long
2. Подсчёт Collections.frequency(strings, s) происходит для каждого элемента коллекции, поэтому надо задать правило для слияния ключей
   (k1, k2) -> k1

```java
List<String> strings =  Arrays.asList("Java", "JaVA", "PHP", "JS", "java", "jS", "Python", "java");


        Map<String, Long> result = strings.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Function.identity(),
                        s -> Long.valueOf(Collections.frequency(strings, s)),
                        (k1, k2) -> k1
                        )
                );
```